# Swift Firebase Auth keeps return false when correct credentials are entered

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm currently implementing a **SwiftUI** login flow using **Firebase Authentication**.
When a user logins into the app, Firebase Auth is supposed to verify the login info and then return true as shown below.

```
func isUserSignedIn() -> Bool {
  authListener = Auth.auth.addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    if user != nil {
      self.signedIn = true
    } else {
      self.signedIn = false
    }
  }
  return self.signedIn
}

func signInToApp(email: String, password: String) -> Bool  {
    var signInSuccess: Bool = false
    if isUserSignedIn() == false {
      Auth.auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { user, error in
        if let error = error, user == nil {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
          signInSuccess = true
        }
      }
    }
    return signInSuccess
}
```

However, when an existing user enters the correct login info, false is returned instead of true. And when false is returned, an alert gets triggered to let the user know that they've entered in the wrong information, however, when the user closes the alert they're able to enter into the next view indicating that they've successfully logged in.

I have tested the login flow against incorrect credentials and that works in the correct manner. If there's an error occurring in **Firebase Auth**, I'm not sure what's happening. I've included the console messages that I get when a user signs in.

```
2021-11-27 15:11:05.058010-0500 FreeFood[465:7547863] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
2021-11-27 15:11:05.148066-0500 FreeFood[465:7547863] GTMSessionFetcher invoking fetch callbacks, data {length = 1399, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 226b696e 64223a20 22696465 ... 33363030 220a7d0a }, error (null)
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to return an asynchronous operation synchronously instead of returning a value use a completion handler or update a variable

Comment: @loremipsum are you referring to the `Auth.auth.signIn` method?

Comment: Both Auth methods are asynchronous